Spring ORM and Hibernate 6.x Migration: SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
I am facing an issue while migrating my Spring 6.1.12 application to use Hibernate 6.5.2.Final with the jakarta.persistence-api version 3.1.0.
The error I encounter during application startup is as follows:
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file:  Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider  does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

Environment:
Spring ORM: 6.1.12
Hibernate: 6.5.2.Final
Persistence API: 3.1.0 (Jakarta EE)
Error Details:
It seems like org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider is being referenced, but it does not implement jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider, which is expected in Jakarta EE 9+ environments.
What I've Tried:
Ensured all dependencies are using jakarta.* packages, but the issue persists.
Double-checked that I’m using the correct Hibernate and Spring versions compatible with Jakarta EE.
How do I properly configure Spring ORM to use Hibernate 6.x with jakarta.persistence APIs?
Is there an alternative way to configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for this setup?
What is the correct persistenceProvider class to use with Hibernate 6.x and Jakarta EE 9+?
Main pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>app</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        scripts/vendor/yui/**/*-coverage.js,
                        scripts/vendor/yui/**/*-debug.js
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>pom.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <java>
                        <eclipse>
                            <version>4.19.0</version>
                        </eclipse>
                    </java>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>apply</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Additional plugins here -->
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>ApplicationResources_de.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>ApplicationResources_fr.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>ApplicationResources_ko.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.fileupload.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-engine-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Additional dependencies here -->
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                    <version>${hikari.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.21.1</aspectj.version>
        <commons.fileupload.version>1.5</commons.fileupload.version>
        <servlet.version>6.1.0</servlet.version>
    </properties>
</project

with model pom.xml
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>server-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>3.2.8</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>app-model</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>app-model</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Formatting plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <java>
            <eclipse>
              <version>4.19.0</version>
            </eclipse>
          </java>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
<!--              <goal>check</goal>-->
              <goal>apply</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- JHusky plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.github.dathin</groupId>
        <artifactId>jhusky</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>

Stacktrace
[INFO] 15:32:00 (main) HikariDataSource - Start completed.
[INFO] 15:32:00 (main) XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file 
    [path-to-webapp/WEB-INF/classes/conf/ac-dataAccess.xml]: 
    Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
[INFO] 15:32:00 (main) HikariDataSource - Shutdown initiated...
[INFO] 15:32:00 (main) HikariDataSource - Shutdown completed.
[INFO] 15:32:00 (main) ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file 
    [path-to-webapp/WEB-INF/classes/conf/ac-dataAccess.xml]: 
    Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:288)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3997)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1130)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1933)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1629)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:385)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:776)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:874)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802)
    ... 52 more


Why did you include the API as that is automatically pulled in by Hibernate already. If you get this message you either have conflicting dependencies (older Spring version) or you have a classloading issue (or both due to a classloading issue). Please add the full stacktrace as well as your pom.xml to the question.

I have excluded hibernate dependency from other dependencies of other projects. And its resolved issue for me.
